# Issues displaying a second form C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have some issues displaying a second form after clicking a specific button in my first form. The question might sound silly, but I am a newbie to programming...

I have added a new Windows form into my project (Form2), but still, when I use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Report()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Report = new Form2();
        Report.Show()
    }
}
}
```

I get the following error

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
>   d:\Projects C#\The Bizzy D\The Bizzy D\Form1.cs 661 13  The Bizzy D

What am I doing wrong then? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That
s pretty much all I have... The parent form is, of course, designed and has other functions which are not causing any issues.

Comment: Good to have more information now - where did you define Form2? Did you define it?

Comment: With the above I am now getting 
Errror 1 Method must have a return type d:\Projects C#\The Bizzy D\The Bizzy D\Form1.cs 18 16 The Bizzy D
And Report() is red underlined

Comment: As I can see, the braces mismatch. I count 3 closing ones missing.

Comment: I forgot to copy the last one, that is not the problem...

Comment: ...you also didn't close `Form2` BTW: did you read a tutorial? Which one?

Comment: Autogenerated code is messed up, delete form2 code create a new form and use that instead.

Comment: Alex, I would love to, but I don'T seem to be able to link the generated and attached form2 in the project to be called by the command, I always get the error 1.

Comment: Also, If I use

        Form Report = new Form();
        private void Button_Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

I can display the form, but I cannot edit its appearance...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) as the error message states. The problem is, that even if you created this second form, the connection between the type name `Form2` and the file it contains isn't clear to C#.

Comment: You should *not* use a `using`statement when calling `Show()`. only do it if you call `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @JensKloster: I see, thanks :) - so `new` may be called even with unknown types, but methods on objects of this type cannot be called?

Comment: Alright, I might sound like a noob, but what exactly do you mean? Like I said, I am a total newbie, so... I have the following using directives

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

As for the namespace, they should be...

Comment: @WolfP. im sorry - I misunerstood that you meant with `using` :|

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Form1 and Form2 are in the same namespace.

Comment: There is aproblem - if I create a new partial class for Form2, I get the same error message

Comment: I think we need more code. Post your Form1 and Form2 classes please.

Comment: public partial class BizzyD : Form
    {
        public BizzyD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Sorry, I inserted something else... All I need is to open another form by clicking a button in form number one. I have form2 added in the project and looksl like I cannot use it for some reason. I must have incorrectly declared or the declaration must be misplaced. :-(

Comment: I guess so, that's why I would like to see more code so we can point you to the source of problem.
You can edit your original post and add code there.

Answer (score 0):

If you Want To Open Form2 On Form1 Button Click Event.

Follow the Below Steps:

> 1. Right Click on Project.
> 2. Add->Windows Form...
> 3. Enter the Form Name : Form2.cs
> 4. Write the following Button Click Event Code in Form1.

```
private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Form2().Show();
        }
```

Comment: Same error

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Projekty C#\The Bizzy D\The Bizzy D\Form1.cs 669 17 The Bizzy D

Comment: Followed step by step - it is not difficult and I have seen that solution before. But for some reason, it is a big NO for me. Form2() is blue underlined

Comment: @user2960580: then please open your project folder and see if the file is created or not.

Comment: It is there. I have diregarded the Form2 constructor, though, as one of the guys above told me it was wrong anyway.